# How to change Date/Time format to English?

Tags: indicator, language-support, locale, date

I have installed **Ubuntu 13.04** and set my local time/date and its working, the only thing that's bugging me is that I cannot change it to English. I would like to do this because it is hard to read and it is not showing it in the proper format in the Terminal, please refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

Show in the proper format

[image]

Not showing in proper format in terminal

How can I change my date/time to English format and keep the local time?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

click on system settings.

[image: System Settings icon in launcher]

Click on Language Support.

[image: Language Support icon in System Settings]

Click on the Regional Formats Tab, and change language to English, and apply system- wide. and that will do it.

Note: You may have to relogin, so changes can take effect

[image: Regional Formats settings]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Mitch. I used it, it works but just as a tip I am writing. We don't need to reboot, we just need to re-login. Just log out and then login again. So, that will make your answer even more efficient and accurate. ;-)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan that makes more sense. +1 for the keynote!

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the answer mitch gave is that after changing regional settings, the alt-shift keyboard language toggle get screwed up.

So you can either fix it with:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle us,?? (where ?? is your other language)
```

Or, you can go for another solution. Instead of doing what mitch suggested, you can change specifically what you want to change.

From the terminal enter `locale` to see a list of the different language variables in your system, and then you can just change them, all, or specific. For example, entering:

```
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
```

will change the date and time back to US-English.

Answer (score 5):

> #### Choose the New York time when installing Ubuntu 13.04, And do the following steps for you local time.

1.Click on settings > Click on **Time & Date**

[image]

It need to me check, By default it will be, if not check it

2.Click on Clock and check **Time in auto-detection location**

[image]

3.Wait few minutes and you will see you local time just above shutdown button

[image]

### OR

[image]

Click on it

**Done**

---

[image]

Comment: This changes the *time and date* not the time and date *format*. -1