# Calendar in Unknown Language

Tags: language-support, firefox-extensions

Just installed Ubuntu 13.04. My system language is English (UK) and everything appears in English. But for some weird reason, the Calendar appears in some south east Asian language with Latin script (my best guess, Vietnamese or Indonesian). Please help me.

Additionally, in most of the pages, the firefox says that it doesn't have the necessary plugins installed to display all the media. Whenever I tell it to search for suitable plugin, it keeps searching for hours. How long should I wait here before the search completes?

Comment: for the calendar issue see if my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265753/how-to-change-date-time-format-to-english-in-ubuntu-13-04/289508#289508) helps you.

Comment: Hi! It seems you have two different questions. It is better to post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!