# Change calendar language to English

Tags: indicator, language-support

The calendar in Ubuntu is not in English. I've installed on two separate machines and the language is still the same. The language system wide is English.

Comment: What language does it look like?

Comment: It shows **Qibxata, 24 Muddee 2013** as todays date. Am sure this is not English but not sure what language it is. But all in all, this the best version of Ubuntu I've installed in 6 Years

Comment: Could you open the language app and download all the available language packs

Comment: @blade19899 installed and still no change. :-(

Comment: Even after restart?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/265753/how-to-change-date-time-format-to-english-in-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: One of the answer in the link that @Mitch posted, might be of help to you, giving your issue. Try this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/289529/36315

Comment: NB: restart is required.

Answer (score 23):

Go to System Settings, then to Language Support. From there open the second tab which is named "Regional Formats". Then change the drop down bar's content from "Arabic" to the English language variant you like and you're all set.

Re-login for this to take effect

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Region & Languages > Formats; click on the formats and change it from your default country to either UnitedStates or UnitedKingdom and then re-log in.. that should do