# How to change the date/time format to English from the command line?

Tags: 16.04, indicator, language-support, locale, date

Following the steps in the thread [How to change Date/Time format to English?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265753/how-to-change-date-time-format-to-english) I got my *Language Support app* crashed, so I wonder if it is possible to change the language of the calendar *from the command line*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably on Ubuntu 16.04, and have run into [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1581567). I recommend that you either wait a few days until it has been fixed through the package updates, or install accountsservice from xenial-proposed in accordance with comment #5 in the bug report.

Answer (score -1):

by changing locale

```
update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

Comment: This *might* changed the way how the format of the timestring the clock uses, nevertheless the language of the calendar remained the same.

Comment: system settings > useraccounts  and try to change language there?
or this package:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=language-selector

Comment: I checked `locale` and there half of the things were changed only to en_US.UTF-8. So I changed `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8`. A logout was also necessary to update these changes. Please improve your answer.

Comment: Well, neither the above answer nor @Matsmaths idea is a good idea, since they both break the handling of languages/locales via the Language Support GUI.

Comment: @FrankSchrijver: No, that doesn't currently work either due to the bug I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson can I rollback to the earlier settings?

Comment: @Matsmath: Sure, you can undo what you changed in `/etc/default/locale`. Basically one line is sufficient: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` (or whatever locale you want as the default). Then, when the bug has been fixed, you can handle the rest via Language Support.