# The days on my lock screen are in another language

Tags: lock-screen, bug-reporting

On my lock screen from Ubuntu 17.10.1, 
the days are not in English but in German,
like 
Monday = Montag
and
Thursday = Donnerstag.

My system standard language is English.
Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Thx for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your current settings are correct:

1. Open **Settings**
2. Go to **Region & Language**
3. Click **Manage installed languages**
4. Under the **Regional Formats** tab, make sure English is selected, then click **Apply System-Wide**

   [image: Regional Formats settings]
5. You may need to log out and log in, or restart the machine, for changes to take effect

<sup>This is based on [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/289508/301745) for an older version of Ubuntu</sup>