# Ubuntu 20.04 Calendar in Foreign Language

Tags: 20.04

The calendar is displaying days of the week in a foreign language, how do I change it to english?

**Edit**: In response to a comment below, this question is not a duplicate of [How to change Date/Time format to English?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265753/how-to-change-date-time-format-to-english).  That thread is 9 years old and the answer refers to a system setting from ubuntu 13, "Language Support", which no longer exists in ubuntu 20.

**Edit #2**: I posted this question in March and only today noticed that it received a reply in October.  Here is the output from locale:

```
$ locale | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
```

In the meantime, the problem went away and my calendar is now displayed in English.  I did not knowingly change anything, maybe the problem got fixed by an update.

Comment: Are you using a language other then English in any part of the your Ubuntu install?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? https://askubuntu.com/questions/265753/how-to-change-date-time-format-to-english

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate.  That thread is 9 years old and refers to system settings from ubuntu 13 which no longer exist in ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if your LC_TIME is set to a different language compared to the system's.

Check them with `locale`.

Try `sudo update-locale LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8` and reboot.